# Excel - copy from other sheet if condition is true

Tags: excel

I have an excel workbook with few sheets (sheet1, sheet2, underlying).
In sheet1 I have "comp" which displays the company name.
I want to search for the company name in sheet2 in "Name" column.
The name in sheet2 does not have to appear exactly as in sheet1.
If the company name from sheet1 appears in column "name" in sheet2 I want to copy 2 values:

1. copy the company code from column "comp_code" in sheet2 to column "underlying_name" in "underlying" sheet.
2. copy company ticker from "ticker" column in sheet1 without the first 4 characters to "ticker" column in "underlying" sheet.

Which functions can I use in this case?
I would greatly appreciate any help. I'm pretty stuck here.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to allow someone to answer you correctly. Maybe add some pictures for more clarity and an example of the desired result.

Comment: @aah9 You won't be able to copy the values unless you used VBA (Macros). Functions and formulas will only "show" the value in the second sheet, by referencing it from the first sheet. Just commenting because you used the word "copy"...